# Display images from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a seperate .png file when the result is from `oneArray` and another .png when the result from the randomiser is from `twoArray`. The pictures will display their rarity. However, when i duplicate the `function displayImage()` bit, it results in nothing? is there another way to do this?

```
function myFunction() {
  var luck = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
    oneArray = ["tree", "dog", "cat", "wood"];
    twoArray = ["tiger", "dot", "tame", "buzz"];
  lucknumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * luck.length));

  if (lucknumber < 8) {
    function displayImage() {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * oneArray.length);
      window.canvas.src = oneArray[num];
    }
    displayImage();
  } else {
    function displayImage() {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * twoArray.length);
      window.canvas.src = twoArray[num];
    };
    displayImage();
  }
}

myFunction();
```

Thank you - i know there's probably many other questions that match this one but not for the scenario i'm currently in D:

Comment: Any errors showing in your console?

Comment: yeah - doSingle() is not defined and unexpected token at line 20 (} else {)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor. We cannot guess what your other code is not doing right

Comment: *when the result is from oneArray* When the result from *what* is `oneArray`?

Comment: Don't create two functions to simply support what could be passed in as a parameter! Also hoisting.

Comment: Don't you need the file extension on the src property?

Comment: The code you show can be coded `var luck=Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1, rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);  window.canvas.src = (luck<8?oneArray[rnd]:twoArray[rnd]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function` are not created at the line it exists in your code. JavaScript scans your code and `function`s are created immediately before any of your code is run. There are two ways to fix this.

Assign the `function` as variables instead:

```
var displayImage = function() {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * oneArray.length);
  window.canvas.src = oneArray[num];
}
```

When you assign as a variable, the declaration (variable name) is the only thing created at the top. The function itself is not created.

But this isn't the cleanest of solutions. Personally, I would refactor and turn both into one function that is compatible with both:

```
function displayImage(array) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  window.canvas.src = array[num];
}
```

Just pass it in the array of choice into the same function

Comment: thanks - but what I'm attempting to ask is if there's a way to display a seperate .png file that displays right next to the randomised choice (which is also a picture)? t

Comment: @Gotenks You say that it results in nothing when you duplicate the function. My answer fixes that. Are you saying it doesn't work at all, even if you only create one function called `displayImage`?

Comment: true, ignore what i said. i wasn't intending to ask about the duplication, but more about the side-by-side images and if it was possible. I'll accept your answer :D

Comment: @Gotenks I saw your comment about your error: `doSingle() is not defined and unexpected token at line 20 (} else {) `. This means that you have an error in a completely different part of your code, I'm afraid. It's what's happening in `doSingle`, or maybe the lack of a function called that.